# Set up maven archetype in Anypoint Studio

Tags: maven-plugin, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

Could anyone please let me know the steps to Run the generate command to create an extension project based on the Maven archetype in Anypoint Studio

mvn org.mule.extensions:mule-extensions-archetype-maven-plugin:1.2.0:generate

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Studio supports executing archetypes. More importantly Studio doesn't support [Mule SDK projects](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started#setup_ide) at this time. Studio 7.6.0 is the last released version at the time of this writing. Even if you create the project in the command line, as the documentation link I shared dictates, you may get unpredictable issues trying to use it inside Studio.

Comment: Corrected the last studio version.